# How to prove the independence of infinite sequence of random variables? (feat. "$N$ bins and $N$ balls" problem)

Tags: pr.probability

Consider a triangular array of random variables
$$X^1_1\\
X^2_1, X^2_2\\
..............\\
X^N_1, X^N_2, ..., X^N_N\\
....................\\
X_1, X_2, ..................
$$

For each $N$ ($N=1,2,\ldots$), the r.v.'s  $X^N_1, ..., X^N_N$ are identically distributed with finite mean and variance but correlated with each other.

We can show that, for any $K$ ($K=1,2,..., N$),
the joint char. function $\phi_{X^N_1, ..., X^N_K}(\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_K) \rightarrow \phi_{X_1}(\theta_1) \cdot \phi_{X_1}(\theta_2) \cdots \phi_{X_1}(\theta_K)$ as $N$ tends to $\infty$.

Can I say $X_1, X_2, ...$ are i.i.d. ?

(Actually I want to show $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X^N_n \stackrel{\text{a.s.}} {\rightarrow}E[X_1]$  as $N \rightarrow 
 \infty$; SLLN)

Remark: All of these come from the well-known "$N$ bins and $N$ balls" problem, the term
$X^N_n$ above representing the number of balls in $n^{\it th}$ bin. Note that $X^N_1, ..., X^N_N$ are *negatively correlated* but the correlation gets weaker as $N$ grows large. By the way, it holds $\sum _{n=1}^N X^N_n = N$.

Comment: You need to assume some boundedness, say, of second moments.  Otherwise imagine replacing a perfectly nice sequence $X^N_i$ with $X^N_i$ with probability $1 - \frac 1 {p_N}$ or $a_N$ with probability $\frac 1 {p_N}$ where $a_N \rightarrow \infty, p_n \rightarrow 0$.  These have the same weak limit, but you can do anything you want with the mean.

Comment: I do not see in the assumptions what prevents the random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ from being equal.

Comment: Yes, all the first and second moments are bounded; there exists M>0 s.t. E[X^N_i], E[(X^N_i)^2] <M for all N and i.

Comment: random variables X_1,X_2,… are obtained as limits of X^N_1,X^N_2,… and we assume they are equal in law but cannot assure if they are independent or not.

Comment: It is unclear in what sense $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are limits of $X^N_1,X^N_2,\dots$.

Comment: You still need to define $X_1,X_2,\dots$, before asking whether they are independent.

Comment: That's the difficulty with this problem.. I cannot define $X_1, X_2,…$ directly, but only through $X^N_1,X^N_2,…$ and their char. function (indirectly). It's easy to show $X_1 \sim {\it Poisson(1)}$.

Comment: So, what is your indirect (or any other) definition of $X_1,X_2,\dots$? Without any definition of $X_1,X_2,\dots$, their independence cannot be possibly proved.

Comment: At least, can prove WLLN with given conditions. Let $
\overline{X}_N {\buildrel \triangle \over =} {1 \over N} \sum_{n=1}^N X^N_n.$ Using pairwise independence, $$
 \operatorname {P} [\Big|\overline{X}_N-E[X_1^N] \Big| \geq \varepsilon]\leq \operatorname{var}[{\overline {X}}_{N}]/\varepsilon ^2 = {1 \over N}
 \operatorname{var}[X^N_1] + {N-1 \over N}\operatorname{cov}[X^N_1, X^N_2] \rightarrow 0.
$$

Comment: I found we don't need the independence of  $X_1,X_2,…$ for the proof of SLLN. Etemadi’s Theorem ([link](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/S0040585X97T990381)) says "pairwise uncorrelated" is enough for SLLN.

Comment: Anyhow, you are consistently saying, the condition "for any $K$ ($K=1,2,..., N$),
the joint char. function $\phi_{X^N_1, ..., X^N_K}(\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_K) \rightarrow \phi_{X_1}(\theta_1) \cdot \phi_{X_1}(\theta_2) \cdots \phi_{X_1}(\theta_K)$" tells nothing about the independence of $X1,X2,…$.

Comment: Indeed, this condition tells us nothing about the independence of $X_1,X_2,\dots$, because (say) $X_2$ is not even mentioned in this condition.

Comment: The condition tells r. vector $(X^N_1,X^N_2, ..., X^N_K)$ converges to $(X_1,X_2, ..., X_K)$ in law and $X_1,X_2, ..., X_K$ are independent and identically distributed. Probably mistaking $\phi_{X_1}(\theta_2)$ as $\phi_{X_1}(\theta_1)$. Check it..